# Add user points for every up vote

Tags: users, userpoints, rating

My drupal 7 site has an user rating system for authors content, but problem is, every up-vote and down-vote do not add point's automatically in users profile. But i think, it is possible by [User Points module](http://drupal.org/project/userpoints). From [Userpoints Karma](http://drupal.org/project/userpoints_karma) module page i have learned that [vote/up down](http://drupal.org/project/vote_up_down) module allows a voter to add or subtract points to the author of a given node or comment, thereby awarding or punishing the author for what they wrote.
So, i have configured [vote/up down](http://drupal.org/project/vote_up_down) module successfully, here is a screenshot of a views of my website:
[image] 
Now my question is, How to add point's automatically for votes using [vote/up down module](http://drupal.org/project/vote_up_down) and [User Points module](http://drupal.org/project/userpoints)? So, if an user vote a content then the user points for that content author will be `10 + 5 = 15`! {Here `10` is previous user point for the content author and `5` is the value for every up-vote!} I can't understand that How to do it automatically? Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Theres is a module to add rules to voting api: http://drupal.org/project/voting_rules

[Userpoints](http://drupal.org/project/userpoints) comes with native rules support.

I just set the whole thing up on my test environment, added a new Rule with

```
Event: User votes on a Node

Condition: User has role(s)
Parameter: User: [vote:user], Roles: authenticated user

Condition: Check the value of the vote
Parameter: Vote: [vote], Operator: is greather than, Data value: 0

Action
Grant points to a user
Parameter: User: [vote:user], Points: 5, Points category: General, Operation: Insert, Moderate: Use the site defaul
```

additional info:
you must enable **userpoints** and **userpoints_rules** as well as **voting_rules**

Here's the export of the rule

```
{ "rules_reward_voter" : {
    "LABEL" : "reward voter",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "voting_rules", "userpoints_rules" ],
    "ON" : [ "voting_rules_insert_node" ],
    "IF" : [
      { "user_has_role" : { "account" : [ "vote:user" ], "roles" : { "value" : { "2" : "2" } } } },
      { "voting_rules_condition_check_vote_value" : { "vote" : [ "vote" ], "operator" : "\u003E", "value" : "0" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "userpoints_action_grant_points" : {
          "user" : [ "vote:user" ],
          "points" : "5",
          "tid" : "0",
          "entity" : [ "" ],
          "operation" : "Insert",
          "display" : 1,
          "moderate" : "default"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: many thanks for the quick reply, but i am just getting stuck while configuring condition in rule? If possible, can you please describe me more about the process?

Comment: I did an update on this

Comment: thankyou so much for your help, i will apply it and knock you again if i get stuck again `;)`

Comment: i found a problem, a up-vote increase user points for the voter but not for the author! also, please do something for the down-vote (-5 point) ... i am a beginner at drupal ... by the way thanks for your help `:)`

Comment: I added the condition. updated the answer :)

Comment: did you used http://drupal.org/project/vote_up_down for voting?

Comment: Actually I did not, I tried vote_up_down a few months before and it was very unstable. I just downloaded it again and got spammed by error messages. Adding the Widget to a view did not work either so I wont dive further into this. As vote_up_down is using votingapi my rule should work though. (condition I added was if vote_value is greater 0). I am not sure if vote_up_down has two different vote sets, if it does than you must remove the condition on value and add some condition on what vote set actually was voted.

Comment: Thanks, but i have stuck here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/60478/minus-userpoints-for-down-votes :) thanks again for the clear concept!

Comment: I have gotten Vote Up/Down to work. It seems to have progressed.

Comment: How do you make the points go to the author? That export above makes them go to the voter.

Comment: instead of `"user" : [ "vote:user" ],` do something like `"user" : [ "node:author" ],` or node:user, not sure what they right target there is, should be available in the token ui

Comment: Any option for D8 similar to this?

Comment: @AdarshKhatri as far as I am aware there are no plans to port userpoints to drupal 8.