# Minus Userpoints for down votes

Tags: rules, userpoints, rating

I have configured [Vote up/down](http://drupal.org/project/vote_up_down) module for voting. For every vote, content author will be awarded 5 points for up-vote, but i am facing problem for down votes! i can not understand how to minus userpoints for down-votes? Say, if a voter hit down vote then 3 point will be minus from userpoints!
**Installed Modules:**

1. [Vote up/down](http://drupal.org/project/vote_up_down)
2. [Userpoints](http://drupal.org/project/userpoints)
3. [Voting API](http://drupal.org/project/votingapi)
4. [Voting Rules](http://drupal.org/project/voting_rules)
5. Rule module...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned on [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/59861/add-user-points-for-every-up-vote/59862#comment66501_59862) already: I guess one of your problems is to determine wether upvote insert rule or downvote insert rule was triggered - vote up/down is storing this in two separate voting sets. (I might be wrong here, when I am good for you).

Let's say it is just one vote set and there are minus votes. you would have to adjust the positive check in the condition to a negative points check. I had my rules still in the environment so I cloned them and did those changes:

(minus points will be probably just negative grants.)

```
Event: User votes on a Node

Condition: User has role(s)
Parameter: User: [vote:user], Roles: authenticated user

Condition: Check the value of the vote
Parameter: Vote: [vote], Operator: is lower than or equal to, Data value: 0

Action
Grant points to a user
Parameter: User: [vote:user], Points: -3, Points category: General, Operation: Insert, Moderate: Use the site default
```

Export:

```
{ "rules_substract_down_voter" : {
    "LABEL" : "substract down voter",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "voting_rules", "userpoints_rules" ],
    "ON" : [ "voting_rules_insert_node" ],
    "IF" : [
      { "user_has_role" : { "account" : [ "vote:user" ], "roles" : { "value" : { "2" : "2" } } } },
      { "voting_rules_condition_check_vote_value" : { "vote" : [ "vote" ], "operator" : "\u003C=", "value" : "0" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "userpoints_action_grant_points" : {
          "user" : [ "vote:user" ],
          "points" : "-3",
          "tid" : "0",
          "entity" : [ "" ],
          "operation" : "Insert",
          "display" : 1,
          "moderate" : "default"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So there are still some things for you to check:

- does vote/up down use one or two rule sets?
- if it uses two, how to determine that in rules?
- if it's only one with negative votes than you're done.

Comment: that's give me sense `:)` Say i have two elements in Conditions section those Operators are is lower than 0, and another one is is greater than 0 (http://i.stack.imgur.com/MfZBS.png). Now my question is how to have two different Actions Elements for those two different Elements of Conditions? Thanks

Comment: you have to implement two separate rules